# Maiden name on wife's CR1 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, philippines

My wife has a US CR1 visa with her maiden name on it. Her Philipines passport has her married name on it. Should she have any issues flying to the US for the first time because of the name difference? She will take her old passport with the maiden name and her marriage certificate with her for backup as well.

Thank you

Comment: I have re-worded the first two sentences, to improve their clarity. If you disagree with my changes, you can revert the changes and restore the original wording.

Comment: Thank you David for clarifying my question. I know there are similar questions to mine but I have not seen any Philippines specific.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you're correctly concerned with the airline's letting her board, and US immigration's letting her into the US. The country that issued her passport, however, is irrelevant. If she carried another non-US passport with the same passport/visa name differences and the same supplementary documents, she'd be treated by both the airline and the US immigration in the same manner. As described in the duplicate question, I would expect no difficulties from either authority.

Comment: Did she replace her passport between applying for the visa and receiving it? I'm having some trouble figuring how she got a visa with her maiden name in her passport with her married name. They don't usually do that sort of thing.

Comment: Good eye! @Christopher: a) What name is in her old passport? b) Is her old passport expired? c) What name is on her current passport? d) What name is on her visa? e) In which passport is the visa affixed?

Comment: My wife has not received her visa yet. I asked the question the way I did to make it less confusing. There is a chance her visa could be issued with her maiden because the NVC has yet to change it. I wanted to see what could happen if the embassy in Manila did issue the visa in her maiden while her passport has a different name. I have been using an immigration attorney and she advised me to change my wife's name before the visa was issued instead of after. My wife got a new passport shortly after we started this whole process last April.

Comment: In the past my attorney never had problems with getting the NVC to fix issues on visa applications but as of now things are at a stand still. We are told be can wait another 4-6 months at the longest to open several more public inquiries before contacting a congressman if the name isn't changed. Our other option is to move forward now and hope my wife's name is changed to match the passport after submitting the DS-260. If that doesn't hopefully it would be fixed at the interview.